# What are the best solutions for randomness in Cardano?

Tags: smart-contract, decentralized-applications

I would like to create a gambling Dapp and for this I need a provably fair RNG. What are the best solutions for provably fair randomness in Cardano

Will Cardano add Chainlink VRF in the future?

Comment: Thanks for asking a question @hanno! It is, though, on the edge of guidelines... 'wen' is almost never helpful question here. 

If you rephrase to ask about the best solutions for randomness in Cardano, I think it will add more value. (And people will be more likely to respond, as that is more in scope).

PS-- I'll answer about how to stay informed in discord :)

Comment: Also, look into the ergo raffle dapp. I would assume they need verifiably fair randomness for that, and it's in EUTxO like Cardano.

Comment: Ergo does not use a provably fair RNG

Comment: Thanks for updating @hanno, and checking out my (ultimately disappointing) reference. Upvoted your question!

Comment: @MatthewCapps you are really great helper as you are trying hard to help. Great attitude
Ergo as I understood is taking randomness from the previous block header

Comment: as I did not get any answer to my question do I need to assume that there is no randomness solution for Cardano?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `genSeed` function from [`Cardano.Crypto.VRF.Praos`](https://input-output-hk.github.io/ouroboros-network/cardano-crypto-praos/Cardano-Crypto-VRF-Praos.html#v:genSeed) module?

This module is the Haskell implementation of [`libsodium`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/libsodium), the library used by Algorand and Cardano to generate Verifiable Random Functions (VRF), which are key at the time of randomly choosing validators in both chains.

Comment: I don't think this can be compiled to Plutus in on-chain code

Comment: Can you please explain the reason? I'm just starting with Plutus and I understand that all Haskell code can be compiled to Plutus.

Comment: Not all Haskell code, we have some [builtins](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-tx/html/PlutusTx-Builtins.html) and only they can be used inside validators. So you wound't be able to use any haskell function at all since they don't use those builtins, but we can use the plutus prelude which contains a bunch of equivalent functions

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

For The Open Source Cardano Lottery, I have created a pseudo random number onchain validator that uses parts of a tx id for the source of a random number.  I am open to any feedback on this approach, but from what I have tested, I can't guess what the winner lotto ticket number will be in advance :)

https://github.com/lley154/cardano-lottery

Comment: But I guess you could "select" the result, since you you can use any of the N UTxOs you have and each UTxO has a different tx id

Comment: To clarify @Mateus, the lottery number is chosen by players before the final close tx is created.  Only after the window to choose a winning number is closed is another transaction created that is used to derive the winning numbers.   So someone would have to predict in advance what a tx id will be - which I believe is not possible.

Comment: I see, so the tx id of the script it self is used?

Comment: yes, but only after the window to choose a winning number is closed.   I created a state machine smart contract that ensures that only when the lotto is in the correct state that a winning number can be chosen from a UTXO (that must inclue the lottery thread token).

Comment: It is not possible to generate random numbers on-chain. In your lottery, you set the winner with the closing transaction. The party doing this will inevitably have the power to chose the winner freely. There is no way to effectively prevent this. using the tx-id does not help. You can fine-tune your UTxO to get the tx-id you need.

Comment: Hi Jey, thanks for your feedback!   The lottery uses a state machine which transitions from a state that players can buy a ticket to a state that players cannot buy a ticket.  It is during this "player can't buy a lottery ticket" that a transaction is created by the lotto admin to draw the winning number.   The winning number is derived by the transaction id locked at the lotto script address which was created by transitioning the to "player can't buy" state.   By using a thread token design pattern, only the lotto admin and only during the proper state can a specific UTXO be used .

Comment: Hi lley154, what mechanism do you think prevents the lottery admin to pick the winning number freely (i.e. setting the tx-id of his choice when transitioning to the state "player can't buy") ?

Comment: Hi Jey,  in order to submit the close transaction, the UTXO must contain the thread token.  So, this prevents the lotto admin from choosing any arbitrary UTXO.  This thread token can only be spent (and then be part of a UTXO) after the lotto numbers have been chosen.   I really need to write up a diagram on this, but really appreciate the questions to see if there are any holes.  I created a youtube video of going throug the lottery process, but not sure (and don't expect) if you'll have time to look at that.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q55nU9mwZYg&t=105s

Comment: I quickly went over the video. You draw your winner from the tx-id. You treat your tx-id as if it was a source of randomness. But it is not. Maybe explain why you think that your lottery has the following 2 properties: i) the party behind the admin cannot steel the pot (through a combination of acting as admin and as a buyer), ii) the winner ticket is not known in advance (i.e. cannot be computed by looking at the blockchain).

Comment: Hi @Jey,  I realized that the tx-id is not a true random number, but I thought it might be sufficiently difficult to predict it several transactions out.  But after doing some more testing, you are correct and it is possible to predict each transaction in advance until you get to the close transaction. There is also nothing to stop the lotto admin from being a player, but this is by design, so the crux of the issue is to make the winning number truly random.  Looks like I will look at using an oracle to salt the winning number selection so it can’t be predicted in advance.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @lley154, you're welcome. In a hobby project, I implemented a lottery that combined (i) a root number committed through a hash at creation by the lottery admin with (ii) a number (either 0 or 1) that every ticket holder could add to he oracle. Thus, the admin would need to buy the whole lottery to pick a ticket at choice. And a normal ticket holder cannot do more than pick at random because he does not know the root number. I'm not sure this approach has no holes, but it looked promising to me.

Comment: Hi @Jey,  interesting approach and I like the idea that each ticket purchased provides entropy.  The only downside I see is that the oracle needs to be updated via ticket purchases and that it may be difficult to easily audit this openly.  Ideally it would be great if the oracle used some publicly known random value so at least there can be an open audit/review once the winning numbers are revealed.   This doesn't prevent the admin from rigging the system, but does allow everyone to know if the lottery was fair.   By using multisig there could be some checks and balances as well.

Comment: Hi @Jey,  I just realized that if you require the number of tickets purchased be greater than the total amount of Ada locked in the lotto contract, this will disincentive the lotto admin from buying all of the lotto tickets.   If you also require ½ of all purchased tickets to be revealed, this prevents predicting the winning number as well.  So, I prefer your approach.  I have submitted a draft proposal in Fund 9, please message me on catalyst if you would like to be a co-proposer and we can discuss level of involvement if interested.  https://cardano.ideascale.com/c/idea/415197

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case, but [nut.link](https://nut.link/) has been submitting the League of Entropy randomness beacon.

Answer (score 0):

Getting randomness into smart contracts is a bit difficult on Cardano due to it's deterministic nature. In some cases, committment schemes can be used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXKf1JwVAOE which rely on the one-way property of hash functions. In this example, it's applied to a game between two parties, which are real competitors, so neither of them wants to reveal their secret information to the other and the outcome is indeed random.
This doesn't work when the different parties might have some incentive to cooperate (e.g. against the operator)

One can also "collect entropy" from multiple parties as it was done here:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/lobster-challenge

One can use a RNG oracle, but still has to deal with the determinism. So even if it's a perfectly fair random number, the gambler might just decide not to play (=submit their tx) in case they would loose. Maybe one can overcome it with validity intervals for tx and penalties for not submitting a tx, but it has some obvious drawbacks.